# How can i use different wow animation

Tags: html, animation

How can I use different wow animation within two div tags, I tried this code, but both animation happen at the same time. I need the animations to happen sequentially.

```
 <div class="game-box wow slideInUp">
      <div class="play wow swing"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your animation is done using CSS, then you could define a rule for tags having `wow` `class` inside another tag having a `wow` `class`:

```
.wow .wow {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

where `2s` is assumed to be the length of the animation.

Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp